# Explain why git status does not list all sub directories in new repo

Tags: git, ionic2

git version 2.12.0.windows.1

I have an existing directory structure ( new ionic 2 project ).

From the windows command prompt...
In the top level of this dir structure I ran `git init.`

I then ran `git status`.

This listed files and some of the directories but not all.

Why are some of the (non-empty) directories not showing up as untracked when others  are ?

Eg.

```
Sw11
--.git
--hooks
    |--readme.md
--src
    |--<various files>
```

`src/` is listed but `hooks/` is not.

Comment: maybe there is a `.gitignore` file with `hooks/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `ionic start app_name --v2` the new app is set up from [Ionic App Base](https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/tree/master/ionic-angular/base) which has a `.gitignore` file. Link [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/blob/master/ionic-angular/base/.gitignore).

If you check your ionic 2 app you will have the same file in the project directory and has a specific entry for `hooks/`.